# Why are my info.plist and .pch files red?

Tags: xcode, xcode6, info.plist

I created a spriteKit Game and later on changed the name of my Project within Xcode. From then on, my .pch and .plist files are red. I will show you an image:

[image]

The app runs fine and builds correctly. I'm not sure if this is a bad thing so that's why I asked. Please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: Those files are not located in your project folder anymore that is why they are red. You might accidentally excluded those files from your project. Check your project folder, if those files are there just drag and drop where they should be.

Comment: Thanks! They were in the correct location but the name of the file did not match. So I went ahead and changed the file names and now they work.

Answer (score 2):

One can open the File Inspector to check a file's absolute path to make sure it is correct.

For team members collaborating via version controls like `git`, also make sure the plist's path is not pushed up to repository as absolute path including e.g. the user's mac usernames.